# how to submit form data using JS ajax without appending it to url?

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to submit a form using ajax javascript and get parameter values by element name in the servlet?
How can I do that without appending it to url while calling through ajax code?

Please guide.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: No am using javascript

Answer (score -1):

Using POST instead GET

using jquery with the method ajax, you have to put your form into a json object

if your form is like this

```
<form id="form1">
....
<input id="idvar1" type="text" name="var1">
<input id="idvar2" type="text" name="var2">
</form>
```

you can use ajax method like this:

```
var data = {'var1': $(#idvar1).val(), 'var2': $(#idvar2).val()};
// or you can simply make
// var data = $("#form1").serialize()
$("#form1").submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data /* here you will send the data of your form */
  });
});
```

here more info about $.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and here more about POST https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

Comment: here you can see how to make a POST only with XMLHttpRequest http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php